# Getting error in accessing Jmeter variables (variable_MarchNr) in yaml in beanshell script

Tags: jmeter, yaml, beanshell, jsr223, blazemeter

I am trying to bulk edit one entity called **issues**, I call GetIssues API and via json extractor, get all issueId's in variable **"issueIds"**

[json extractor to extract issueIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpN50.png)

Now I want to pass these Ids in other api bulk edit issues, If I directly use these array in next API, I get below error:
{"details":"Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 19","metadata":{}}

So I used to below code in Beanshell Post processor:

```
var mylist;
props.put("mylist", new ArrayList());
log.info("Detected " + vars.get("issueIds_matchNr") + " issueIds");
for (int i=1; i<= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("issueIds_matchNr")); i++) {
    log.info("IDs # " + i + ": " + vars.get("issueIds_" + i));
    props.get("mylist").add('"'  +  vars.get("issueIds_" + i)  + '"' );
}
log.info(props.get("mylist").toString());
var issueIdList;
vars.put("issueIdList", props.get("mylist").toString());
log.info(vars.get("issueIdList"));
```

In my next api call if I pass issueIdList variable, then this works fine in jmeter.

sample variable values in debug sampler are like:

```
issueIdList=["555bcfc2", "33974d2c", "e58db1d6"]
issueIds_1=555bcfc2
issueIds_2=33974d2c
issueIds_3=e58db1d6
issueIds_matchNr=3
```

Problem I am facing if I convert my jmx2yaml and tried to run this file with
bzt issues.yml

then while executing above shell script, these issueIds_matchNr, issueIds_3 are not detected,  I get below error;

```
2022-05-29 08:26:10,785 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223PostProcessor: Detected null issueIds
2022-05-29 08:26:10,795 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: eval stream : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt : at Line: 4 : in file: eval stream : Integer .parseInt ( vars .get ( "issueIds_matchNr" ) ) 
Target exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 in eval stream at line number 4
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:87) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
```

My Yaml script is:

```
- extract-jsonpath:
        issueIds:
          default: NotFound
          jsonpath: $..id
      follow-redirects: true
      jsr223:
      - compile-cache: true
        execute: after
        language: beanshell
        parameters: issueIds
        script-file: script.bsh
      label: Get Issue Id's
      method: GET
      url: https://${BASE_URL1}/${PROJECT_ID}/issues?limit=5&sortBy=-displayId&filter%5Bvalid%5D=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one important bit: setting the Match Nr in your [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/)

The correct definition of the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) would be something like:

```
extract-jsonpath: 
 issueIds:
   jsonpath: $..id
   match-no: -1 #this is what you need to add
```

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy as the scripting language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/) so consider migrating, it will be as simple as removing the first line from your script.bsh

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri, it was great help. Worked :-)